# wordpress get permalink format in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not great with the wordpress api for php but I'm looking for a way to return the permalink format in php I've tried over here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference

but nothing jumps out. In the [admin settings for WP i have a few options](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/a/ad/permalink-settings.png)

what I really want is a way of getting this in php like:

```
get_permalink_format();  // would give me the rewrite rule as a string?
```

Can anyone throw me a bone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo get_option('permalink_structure');
?>
```